# need to import tensorflow_hub

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting below error while trying to import tensorflow_hub. I have applied the already available solutions on Github or on stackoverflow and even downgraded my tesnorflow and estimator too. Still I am getting below. Can you please help ?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dnn_logit_fn_builder' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\kumar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py)
```

code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```

Comment: You sure the error comes from `import tensorflow_hub as hub`, and not from the previous line? In any case, you are expected to include the full error trace here, please see how to create a [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given code worked fine with `Tf v2.8 and v2.9.1`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
import tensorflow_hub as hub
```